# Fetch Google Calendar Entries from Google Calendar

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I am trying to write a python script that allows you to fetch entries from a google calendar. 
I tried using the Google Calendar API with the example here: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python

```
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
import datetime

# Setup the Calendar API
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

# Call the Calendar API
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time
print('Getting the upcoming 10 events')
events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                              maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                              orderBy='startTime').execute()
events = events_result.get('items', [])

if not events:
    print('No upcoming events found.')
for event in events:
    start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
    print(start, event['summary'])
```

When I run this with the command line "python quickstart.py" I am getting a

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apiclient.discovery'
```

I tried installing the google api python clients but that still did not work.

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
conda install -c conda-forge google-api-python-client
```

Are there any other suggestions for how to fetch google calendar entries with python?

Comment: python2 or python3? Assuming pip actually did something, where did it install the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch calendars and events from google first you need a client_secret.json to get access to google calendar resources.

Do not use the [oauth2client library](https://github.com/google/oauth2client), because it's deprecated. Instead, use [google auth](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python).

You can use Flow or InstalledAppFlow from [google auth oauthlib](http://google-auth-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google_auth_oauthlib.flow.html) to gain access to google calendar account resources.

```
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
    'secret_file.json',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
)
credentials = flow.run_console()
```

Dump this credentials into a file, so you won't need to ask for permission access again.

```
service = build(
    'calendar',
    'v3',
    credentials=credentials
)
```

With this service you can use all the google calendar api from [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/).

**Update:**

Since I don't use oauth2client library I dump the credentials manually:

```
with open('credentials.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps({
        'token': credentials.token,
        'refresh_token': credentials.refresh_token,
        'token_uri': credentials.token_uri,
        'client_id': credentials.client_id,
        'client_secret': credentials.client_secret,
        'scopes': credentials.scopes}))
```

Comment: @PandaPanda I just dump into a credentials.json file, see my updated answer to see the json dump format.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use the private ical URLs (listed in calendar settings) of your calendars and then parsing the retrieved calendar file. This works without the need for OAuth. You will not be able to retrive a list of these URLs, the user needs to look them up himself.